# Rails is routing my calendar_event_path backwards?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Rails is giving me urls that have the ids in the wrong order. It's handing the parent id to the child and the child id to the parent.

In my routes.rb I have

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :events
end
```

which `rake routes` tells me is setting up good routes, e.g.

```
calendar_event GET    /calendars/:calendar_id/events/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"events", :action=>"show"}
```

So when I ask for the path for that route from my view partial,

```
<%= link_to "#{event.name} @ #{event.calendar.name} #{event.calendar.year}", calendar_event_path(event) %>
```

it gives me a url that has the ids reversed...

```
http://localhost:3000/calendars/<-eventid->/events/<-calendarid->
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Edit: in my model, Event `belongs_to :calendar` and Calendar `has_many :events`. I'm also using Mongoid as my ORM, not ActiveRecord, though I hope that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the nested resource's URL helper `calendar_event_path` you need to provide it the `calendar` object (or ID) too, eg:

```
 calendar_event_path(event.calendar, event)
```

An alternative is:

```
 <%= link_to "#{event.name} @ #{event.calendar.name} #{event.calendar.year}", [event.calendar, event] %>
```

Comment: To explain further: Rails will assume you mean the current parameter if you don't pass a valid ID through, so if `params[:id]` is set, it will assume that.

Comment: How do you use a second param? for example if working with  /squad/id/user/id, both squads and users have IDs

Answer (score 0):

If you rename :id to another name would that change the link thats generated? I think the default is to use :id in the parameters to identify the resource specified in link_to.